# How to download entire youtube playlist with embedded chapter information on ytdl / ytdlp?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, ytdl, yt-dlp

I use this to download individual files with chapter information. ▶️

```py
yt-dlp -f "bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]" -o "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" --embed-chapters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=
```

I tried doing

```py
yt-dlp -f "bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]" -o --yes-playlist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" --embed-chapters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywyQ_eNNCJU&list=PLI84Sf0aDgazRojpYTLTXFE6Iaf5bkYr_
```

But it gives out error

> ERROR: Fixed output name but more than one file to download:
> --yes-playlist 'list' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What is the command line to download the entire Youtube playlist with chapter information embedded in each video using ytdl / ytdlp ?

Answer (score 5):

Wrong position for parameter `--yes-playlist`.
Put that before `-o`:
`yt-dlp -f "bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]" --yes-playlist -o "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s" --embed-chapters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywyQ_eNNCJU&list=PLI84Sf0aDgazRojpYTLTXFE6Iaf5bkYr_`

Comment: Is it really necessary to specify the maximum height for the audio part, too?

Comment: No, I simply complied with the requirements of the author's use case